# Laravel Pagination issue, after 1st page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination

I am facing issue of laravel pagination.
I am using code like this

```
$list = DB::table('person')->join('abc','person.id','=','abc.id')->where('name','=',$name)->paginate(15);
```

and i view file

```
echo $lists->appends($get)->links();
```

It Works for the first page and than its shows every link like

`localhost/projects/abc/persons?page=2`

if you have any suggestion please let me know

Comment: What do you expect the link to be? I don't understand what your issue is.

Comment: That's normal, pagination uses the querystring to know which page you are on.

Comment: the link should be ?page=2 and ?page=3 and so on... but its ?page=2 on evey link

Comment: what is value of $get?

Comment: When i am appending $_GET  parameters by mistake i am also appending the page varibale that's why its all over page=2